# Selenium 4 keeps opening a default Firefox instance

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

I am currently learning Selenium 4 on Python 3.12 to automate web tasks and whenever I run my code, it will open another Firefox instance with the default settings of everything.

I want to make my program open in my default Firefox profile if the browser isn't running or open it in a new tab if Firefox is already running, then close the tab once it is done.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

# code stuffs here
```

I suspect it's opening a new profile but it doesn't seem to generate a new profile every time I run it. I also deleted all redundant and unused profiles, but it will still open a defaulted Firefox instance.